# The sed command is not working as expected in csh to remove tags

Tags: unix, csh

Let's assume I have my_file:

```
First line
<file>dsdsd</file>
Middle line
<file>sdsfs</file>
<file>asasa</file>
End line
```

After this command:

```
sed -i '/<file>/,/<\/file>/d' my_file
```

I expect to see only these lines:

```
First line
Middle line
End line
```

Why do I see only the "First line" ?
How to fix it ?
It's just an example of the text. My goal: remove all  tags from the file.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex like this to remove the lines

```
sed -i '/<file>.*<\/file>/d' my_file
```

However, if your intention is to parse XML/HTML you may need other tools rather than `sed`.